# Windows CA issue intermediate CA certificate

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, certificate-authority

When trying to issue an intermediate CA cert I have created a template which sets the x509 basic constraint for CA, but I have intentionally left 'critical' off.

When I create a certificate with this template the certificate created has the basic constraints marked as critical. It seems as though the CA is overriding my template and making the constraint critical.

Even if I use `certutil` to set the extension value of basic constraints. once I issue the certificate it has changed back to critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because CA policy module overrides this setting. Policy module follows its own rules (which may not be consistent with request settings) to fix some mistakes or unsupported fields in the request. Non-critical Basic Constraints for CA certs is not allowed by RFC, therefore it is set to critical during certificate signing.